# List<int> takes long time to instantiate with Nhibernate Criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, list, criteria

I have this query which returns 7 rows and takes 4ms in the database but 1075ms to instantiate. That is just one example of the times and it varies on the objects but it doesn't seem to make sense that it takes so long. Any pointers on how to increase the speed?

```
var criteria =
                GetSession().CreateSQLQuery(
                    @"
                    select circt_id as CircuitId from normal_upstream
                        where dni_equip_type = 'A'

                        start with up_equip_stn_no in (:UpStationNo1)
                        connect by prior equip_stn_no = up_equip_stn_no
                        union
                        select circt_id as CircuitId
                        from normal_upstream 
                        where up_equip_stn_no in (:UpStationNo1)")
                    .AddScalar("CircuitId", NHibernateUtil.Int32).SetParameterList("UpStationNo1",upstreamStations)
                    .List<int>()
```

SQL Query generated

```
   select
     circt_id as CircuitId 
from normal_upstream

where dni_equip_type = 'A'

                            start with up_equip_stn_no in (
    'B' /* :p0 */)
                        connect by prior equip_stn_no = up_equip_stn_no
                        union
                        select
 circt_id as CircuitId
                        from normal_upstream       
where up_equip_stn_no in (
    'B' /* :p1 */)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does it take this long every time it is run or just the first time?  Which byte code generator are you using?

Comment: @jonnii, It takes a long time every time. Also the byte code is NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.

Comment: @Gage what happens if you change it to returning an IEnumerable instead of IEnumerable<int> and use List()?

Comment: @jonnii, I tried to use .Enumerable() but it says SQL queries don't support that. But when I use .List() it still takes just as long. It did however speed up a different query that uses that list from this query.

Comment: @Gage I can't see anything necessarily wrong with this, perhaps it's the HQL compiler?  What happens if you hard code the sql?

Comment: @Gage I suggest you use a performance profiler like ANTS or dotTrace to find out where the time is being spent. Psychic debugging is not fun.

Comment: @jonnii, Any idea why SetParameterList would slow it down so much?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently what was slowing it down was the SetParameterList call. When I format the SQL before I get something along the lines of 8ms database and 485ms instantiation, which is acceptable. I'd like to have something faster but that will do for now.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
var sql =
            String.Format(
                @"select circt_id as CircuitId from normal_upstream
                where dni_equip_type = 'FDR_OCR'
                        start with up_equip_stn_no in ({0})
                        connect by prior equip_stn_no = up_equip_stn_no
                        union
                        select circt_id as CircuitId
                        from normal_upstream 
                        where up_equip_stn_no in ({0})",
                String.Join(",",upstreamStations.Select(x=>"'"+x+"'").ToArray()));
        var criteria =
            GetSession().CreateSQLQuery(sql)
                .AddScalar("CircuitId", NHibernateUtil.Int32)
                .List();
            return criteria;
```

Comment: which version of NH are you using?

Comment: strange. i've used SetParameterList in various scenarios and types, i've never seen a perf hit. Was the upstreamStations an int[] or something else?

Comment: @Jaguar, It was an array originally but is now a List<string>. Same performance though. Which list type would produce the best performance? Any ideas?

Comment: i usually pass arrays (int, string for the time being) and having checked my code, for the most of them i wouldn't even use the overload where you define the IType.... how many items did the upstreamStations var contain, for the 1045ms execution?

Comment: @Jaguar, It contained one string for 1045ms. The other test which was 485ms contained 4 strings.

Comment: meh, at this point i would have to point to Diego's suggestion, use a profiler to see what's slowing you down... Also, i would suggest that if :UpStationNo1 values can be obtained directly in the query with a join, you could take that route...